# How to make RadMenu root items justified?

Tags: css, telerik, radmenu

Specifically, how would I do this **without** any JavaScript?

I have a RadMenu that I made 1080px wide, I have about 7 items in it so they only take up about 2/3 of that width.

I want force the items to split the width of the whole RadMenu between them so there's no awkward blank area on either side.
(Similar to using Justify on a RadTab)

Can this be achieved with CSS, or existing functionality of the RadMenu?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to play with the padding element of the RadMenu and adjust the right and left side to get the desired with you want.

```
.RadMenu .rmRootGroup .rmRootLink {
    padding: .25em .54em .35em .50em;
}
```

Remember the order is top, right, bottom, left.

Comment: In essence I'm setting the padding of the individual menu items to a screen-space flexible size?

If I'm reading the solution correctly then I'll have to hand-manage this if the number of menu items ever change.  This seems like a serious shortcoming on Telerik's end, especially given that the Tabs have good layout.